# How to communicate between two Java applications each on a different computer and not on the same WiFi

Tags: java

Assume I have two Java applications each running on a different computer and not on the same WiFi, how would I be able to communicate between them? For example: How do I send a `String` from one application to the other application?

Comment: well, are they on internet? do they have network connectivity at all?

Comment: The simplest and most reliable way (provided they both have access to the internet) is to have a central server that both can reach that will coordinate and pass on messages between them.

Comment: @JoachimSauer How does one do that in Java? Do you know a tutorial or a source where I can read more about it? And yes, they do have access to the internet, but I was not able to figure out how I would communicate between them...

Comment: Is one of them in a  server role? Set up a rest service, e.g., with Spring Boot, and have the other connect to that.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about the tightly coupled application where you know the locations of the sender and receiver, So this can be achieved by RMI (Remote Method Invocation) But for the loosely coupled you may use JMS (Java Message Service) API.

You may checkout the document for that... and surely it will resolve your purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I will check out the documentation on the JMS API and do a little research on RMI. Do you know good tutorials or something like that?

Comment: I'd rather go for the second option and use JMS. Lookup tutorials for a **message bus**.

Comment: You may follow the tutorial given on oracle doc. Here is the link for JMS https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jms-concepts003.htm